# View contents of a second monitor on the primary display

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have a requirement to be able to see what is being displayed on the second monitor connected to a macbook on the primary display. I can't use mirroring for this because I will doing something different on the primary display. I need to be able to see the second monitor display in a window.

I am going to be connected to a large display on stage and (potentially) won't be able to see it.

Does anyone know if there are any apps that will allow this specific functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two apps I've seen that claim to give a picture-in-picture type view of the secondary display: [Displays](https://www.jibapps.com/apps/displays/) and [Side Mirror](https://sidemirrorapp.com). Neither is free, but such is life.

Alternately, MacOS (since High Sierra, I think) allows you to arrange multiple displays in complex ways. You *could* add a third display (or an iPad, if your system supports SideCar), and mirror that to your secondary display, leaving your primary display in extended desktop mode with the secondary. Apple's instructions [are here](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-multiple-displays-mchl7c7ebe08/mac).

Comment: Thanks, I went with Displays eventually. This did exactly what I wanted.